# Domain redirected you too many times

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache web server.

I would like to setup a reverse proxy to access a local application running on port 9090.

Here is my apache configuration :

```
ProxyRequests Off

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA

# Redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/example.com/public_html"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/example.com/public_html"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9090/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RequestHeader unset Origin
</VirtualHost>
```

The configuration is not working. I'm getting the error : example.com redirected you too many times

The server is hosted at a windows 10 EC2 AWS instance.

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no obvious redirection loop in your Apache config, but the server at port `9000` could also try to redirect `HTTP` to `HTTPS`. What is running on that port?

Comment: You need to separate the secure, and insecure sections. As apache is redirecting insecure to secure. Also, you should use the **Listen portnum** and <VirtualHost *:portnum>, and **not** NameVirtualHost *:portnum